# Inverse of `Flow.batch` in akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Is there an inverse to `Flow.batch`

I want the signature of the method to be `Flow[Vector[T],T,NotUsed]`

It should unwrap a `Vector` and emit every element of the `Vector` downstream as a single element.

Comment: `.mapConcat(identity)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Levi said in a comment, the answer is `mapConcat`. As [the docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapConcat.html) say this operator "transform each element into zero or more elements that are individually passed downstream. This can be used to flatten collections into individual stream elements."

Also see `flatmapConcat` if you want to produce a source rather than an iterable.

Comment: Can you add the actual answer to your comment? I.e. `.mapConcat(identity)`